# How to Check if request.GET var is None?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting into django and this is getting me a headache. I'm trying to get a simple GET variable. URL is **site.com/search/?q=search-term**

My view is:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET.get('q', None)
        if q is not None:
            results = Task.objects.filter(
                                   Q(title__contains=q)
                                   |
                                   Q(description__contains=q),
                                   )
            ...return...
        else:
            ...
    else:
        ...
```

Search queries like **mysite.com/search/?** (without q) get through the first if correctly.

The problem is in queries like **mysite.com/search/?q=**. They don't get caught by `if q is not None:`

So, the short answer would be How can I check `q == None`? (I've already tried `''`, `None`, etc, to no avail.)

Comment: A simple **if q** instead of **if q is not None (or '')** did the trick. Anyone has an explanation for this?

Comment: In general, you need to be very cautious about using the `is` operator in Python. Normally you want an equality test (`==`), not an identity test (`is`).  A sequence of non-zero length tests `True`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First, check if the `request.GET` dict contains a parameter named `q`. You're doing this properly already:

```
if request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in request.GET:
```

Next, check if the value of `q` is either `None` or the empty string. To do that, you can write this:

```
q = request.GET['q']
if q is not None and q != '':
    # Do processing here
```

Notice that it is not necessary to write `request.GET.get('q', None)`. We've already checked to make sure there is a `'q'` key inside the `request.GET` dict, so we can grab the value directly. The only time you should use the `get` method is if you're not sure a dict has a certain key and want to avoid raising a KeyError exception.

However, there is an even better solution based on the following facts:

- The value `None` evaluates to `False`
- The empty string `''` also evaluates to `False`
- Any non-empty string evaluates to `True`.

So now you can write:

```
q = request.GET['q']
if q:
    # Do processing here
```

See these other resources for more details:

- [Python: Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
- [Python: `dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: Thanks, this is great info.
Plus, I was feeling guilty to mark my own answer as correct :D

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the clarification by [@Ned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145403/ned-deily).
Found a complete explanation [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-April/013932.html).

Basically:

> '==' can be thought of as "value equality", that is, if two things look
>   the same, == should return a true value.  (For those with a Java
>   background, Python's == is actually doing something akin to an equals()
>   method.)
>
> 'is' can be thought of as 'object
>   identity', that is, if the two things
>   actually are the same object.