# Is there a standard client behaviour for submitting an empty select multiple?

Tags: html, select, standards

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-SELECT

Doesn't specify how the client should behave if the submitted select multiple is empty. Does anyone know whether there is a standard for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I do not have the time to test this, but I hope the following can help you...

If I am not mistaken, the first element is selected by default when the page is loaded. Therefore, create a very simple HTML file with a `form` and a `select` that has the `multiple` attribute active and with a few `options`. Then, open the file to see what happens in a few browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari.

Another thing would be to look what HTML5 says about this here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-select-element.

**UPDATE**

The W3C HTML 4.01 standard states this (scroll a bit down in the link you provided):

> 17.6.1 Pre-selected options
>
> Zero or more choices may be
>   pre-selected for the user. User agents
>   should determine which choices are
>   pre-selected as follows:
>
> If **no OPTION element has the selected**
>   attribute set, user agent behavior for
>   choosing which option is initially
>   selected is undefined. Note. Since
>   existing implementations handle this
>   case differently, the current
>   specification differs from RFC 1866
>   ([RFC1866] section 8.1.3), which
>   states: The initial state has the
>   first option selected, unless a
>   SELECTED attribute is present on any
>   of the  elements. **Since user
>   agent behavior differs, authors should
>   ensure that each menu includes a
>   default pre-selected OPTION.**
>
> If one OPTION element has the selected
>   attribute set, it should be
>   pre-selected. If the SELECT element
>   has the multiple attribute set and
>   more than one OPTION element has the
>   selected attribute set, they should
>   all be pre-selected. It is considered
>   an error if more than one OPTION
>   element has the selected attribute set
>   and the SELECT element does not have
>   the multiple attribute set. User
>   agents may vary in how they handle
>   this error, but should not pre-select
>   more than one choice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, @Alerty is mistaken.  If the multiple attribute is present on the select element but none of the option elements have the selected attribute, then *no* element is selected by default.  (Tested on IE 9, FF 5, Chrome 13, and Safari 5 on Win 7.)

So, what should the web browser do if the user doesn't select anything yet submits the form?  It should do exactly what you would expect:  Submit no selection.  And that's exactly what the current version of the HTML5 spec says:

"The multiple attribute is a boolean attribute. If the attribute is present, then the select element represents a control for selecting *zero* or more options from the list of options."

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-select-element

Comment: `the select element represents a control for selecting zero or more options from the list of options.` to me, that suggests that the browser should behave the same way if 1...N options where selected than if 0 were selected. Furthermore, I think that @Alerty is perfectly right, I checked the spec and it clearly says "user agent behavior for choosing which option is initially selected is undefined" which would suppose that if 0 options are selected, there should be one anyways, and the user agent should choose it, ... that is actually very unclear ...

Comment: Ok.  But apparently these 4 browser vendors don't read the spec the same way you do.  :-)

Comment: I don't know ! Maybe they had a secret meeting in which they all agreed on that !major! problem :) I don't know if it is indeed specified clearly somewhere, or if they just copied on each other to have the same behaviour, or if it is just a coincidence ... But you'll have to admit that those quotations from the specs are not really clear about that ... don't you think ?