# What is the meaning of 'q' in request.GET var?

Tags: python, django

Following to this question: [How to Check if request.GET var is None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422055/how-to-check-if-request-get-var-is-none)

I have this function in view.py:

```
def search(request):
    error = False
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        if not q:
            error = True
        else:
          .....
```

it takes a string and search for it.... I don't understand the `'q'` part.

I'm assuming its part of the URL pattern of the query: `/search/?q=....`
but I don't see where I set up this exact pattern.

Why it has to be `'q'`? what is the meaning of it?

Comment: it is a parameter lets say myurl.com/?q=myValue so you are able to get the get value via GET using HTTP protocol.

Comment: it can be ?query= ?q= ?post= etc... you just have to make sure that your Django app reads this parameters but its not mandatory.

Comment: Just so that I'll understand.. suppose I want to change this to `/search/?b=...` what changes do I have to make? I don't understand where is the connection between the search function and the URL.... I don't see how it creates the pattern of `/?q=....`

Comment: you need to pass a search term right? lets say tomatoe so you use /search/?query=tomatoe so you use request.GET['query'] and you get the value tomatoe.

Comment: i understand that.. i just don't understand where this 'q' is defined.

Comment: the Q is defined on your browser. you are just using python to read the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the param given in url:

```
...com/?q=variable
```

So in view you have a dict `request.GET` and `q` is the key and `variable` is the  value:

```
{'q': 'variable'}
```

If you want to change it in url, like this:

```
...com/?b=...
```

You will need to change in your view:

```
def search(request):
    error = False
    if 'b' in request.GET:
        b = request.GET['b']
        if not b:
            error = True
        else:
          .....
```

As you can see, just replace `q` by `b` or whatever you want to be the name of your param.